# CSS transition not working for right most div on offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I have five divs. Four of those divs you can click, which will run a function that moves the div you clicked on to the coordinate of the fifth div using `div.offsetLeft` and `div.offsetTop`. The first three divs all work fine, but if you click the right most div first, the transition effect isn't applied while moving to the coordinates. If you click any of the other divs first, and then the right most div, the transition will apply.

If you make it so there are only two or three divs, the problem still persists. (You must remove the corresponding id from the parties array, as well as the html element).

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zjystr2u/

Apologies for the javascript in the html. Have never used jsfiddle, and couldn't figure out how to make it load the javascript after the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something janky is going on when you `getCurrentPosAll()` changes `position` from the default `static` to `absolute`

You could run `getCurrentPosAll()` before changing the `top` and `left` to set their default values correctly.

```js
var selected = document.getElementById("selected");
var selectedX = selected.offsetLeft;
var selectedY = selected.offsetTop;

parties = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4'];
getCurrentPosAll(); // (NEW) Make sure their defaults are set.

function moreTest(e) {
  var party = e.target
  party.style.left = selectedX + "px";
  party.style.top = selectedY + "px";
}

function getCurrentPosAll() {
  for (var idx = 0; idx < parties.length; idx++) {
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById(parties[idx]);
    var x = currentDiv.offsetLeft;
    var y = currentDiv.offsetTop;
    currentDiv.style.left = x + "px";
    currentDiv.style.top = y + "px";
  }

  for (var idx = 0; idx < parties.length; idx++) {
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById(parties[idx]);
    currentDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.selected {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 1;
}

.opt {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: top 0.7s, left 0.7s;
}

.opt1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.opt2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.opt3 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.opt4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="selected" id="selected"></div>
  <div class="opt opt1" id="opt1" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt2" id="opt2" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt3" id="opt3" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt4" id="opt4" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it behaves like this. I figure it has to do with how and *when*  the browser calculates the initial value for the transition. where last elements CSS changes get *batched* into 1 update.
therefor it will immediately receive the updated `top` and `left` values, whereas the other elements will receive 2 updates, one with the default `top` and `left` and then one with the updated values. causing their transition to work properly.
Most likely because the the last elements CSS is changed, their css updates are applied in 2  updates instead of 1.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it had something to do with the function not finishing before the last div moves. I was calling that function onclick because it previously worked differently. Now I realize there's no reason to have it in the onclick function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not that the function doesn't finish before moving, It's because CSS changes are batched into single updates for performance reasons. Like when you update the left property in a loop, [All changes get batched into 1 update](https://jsfiddle.net/zjystr2u/2/). We don't see this for the first 3 elements because another elements CSS is changed in between. resulting in separate batches

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selected = document.getElementById("selected");
var selectedX = selected.offsetLeft;
var selectedY = selected.offsetTop;

parties = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4', 'opt5','opt6'];

function moreTest(e) {
 var party = e.target
  getCurrentPosAll();
  party.style.left = selectedX + "px";
  party.style.top = selectedY + "px";
}

function getCurrentPosAll() {
 for (var idx = 0; idx < parties.length; idx++) {
   var currentDiv = document.getElementById(parties[idx]);
    var x = currentDiv.offsetLeft;
    var y = currentDiv.offsetTop;
    currentDiv.style.left = x + "px";
    currentDiv.style.top = y + "px";
  }
  
  for (var idx = 0; idx < parties.length; idx++) {
   var currentDiv = document.getElementById(parties[idx]);
    currentDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
  .selected {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .opt {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }
  .opt1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .opt2 {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .opt3 {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  .opt4 {
    background-color: green;
  }
  .opt5 {
    background-color: violet;
  }
  .opt6 {
    background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="selected" id="selected"></div>
  <div class="opt opt1" id="opt1" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt2" id="opt2" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt3" id="opt3" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt4" id="opt4" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt5" id="opt5" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
  <div class="opt opt6" id="opt6" onclick="moreTest(event)"></div>
</div>
```